# Get row indexes of H2O dataframe when split into train and test

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, h2o

I am new to H2O. So far for the train-test split I have used the StratifiedKFold() of sklearn.

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):               
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

I need the indexes for some further processing later.

In H2O I can't figure out how to get the indexes while doing cross validation. From what I have gathered via videos and blogs, this is how we do CV in H2O:

```
gbm_model = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(model_id = 'gbm_model',nfolds=5)
```

How do I get the train and test indexes of each fold?

Also, how do I get the indexes while doing a simple split?

```
data_split = data.split_frame(ratios=[0.8],seed = 1234)
train_df = data_split[0]
test_df = data_split[1]
```

How do I get the indexes that went into train and test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `stratified_kfold_column(n_folds=3, seed=-1)` or `stratified_split(test_frac=0.2, seed=-1)` which create a column with the splits you can use to subset to split on later.

see more about these in the [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html?highlight=stratified_kfold_column#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.stratified_kfold_column)